# How to match similar shapes using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to match objects and shapes using the OpenCV library.

[image]

```
def find_contr(path, path2):
    matchs = []
    saved_contour_shapes = []
    saved_contour_target = []
    
    target = path2
    shapes = cv2.imread(path)

    # target = cv2.resize(target, dsize=(500, 500), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)

    shapesGray = cv2.cvtColor(shapes, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    targetGray = cv2.cvtColor(target, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    targetBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(targetGray, (5, 5), 3)

    ret, shapesTh = cv2.threshold(shapesGray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    targetTh = cv2.Canny(targetBlur, 150, 250)

   
    cntrs_shapes, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(shapesTh, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cntrs_target, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(targetTh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    cntrs_target = sorted(cntrs_target, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)


    cv2.drawContours(target, cntrs_target[0], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
    for contr in cntrs_shapes:
        match = cv2.matchShapes(cntrs_target[0], contr, cv2.CONTOURS_MATCH_I3, 0)
        matchs.append((match, contr))

    matchs.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    cv2.drawContours(target, cntrs_target[0], -1, (0,255,0),3)
    cv2.drawContours(shapes, [matchs[0][1]], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
    cv2.imshow('target', target)
    cv2.imshow('shapes', shapes)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def perform_grabcut(image_path, rect):
    # Load the image
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    image = cv2.resize(image, dsize=(500, 500), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)

    # Create a mask with zeros initially
    mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], np.uint8)

    # Set the background and foreground model
    bgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
    fgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)

    # Apply GrabCut on the specified ROI
    cv2.grabCut(image, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

    # Create a mask where the probable foreground is set to 1 and the others to 0
    mask_probable_foreground = np.where((mask == 2) | (mask == 0), 0, 1).astype('uint8')

    # Apply the mask to the original image
    image_with_background_removed = image * mask_probable_foreground[:, :, np.newaxis]

    # Display the result
    cv2.imshow("Original Image", image)
    cv2.imshow("Image with Background Removed", image_with_background_removed)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return image_with_background_removed
```

I found the contour while erasing the background other than the object using Grabcut().
However, is there a way to improve the recognition of pentagons instead of circles?

I want to use only image processing rather than creating a deep learning model like tensorflow.